# create rpm containing a python program

Tags: python, linux, rpm

I have a python program running in a virtual enviroment with some external modules.

I would like to create a "package" ideally an rpm which contains everything you need
to run the program.
So I would like to do:

rpm -i filename.rpm

and the program to be installed and ready for use without any other user interaction.

Can you please give me some instructions?

Comment: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-build.html

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of packaging Python code is with [distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/index.html#distutils-index).  The instructions for creating an rpm are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-rpm-packages).  You use [requires](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages) to specify dependencies on other packages.